# PHP database connecting error

Tags: php, sql, database

I am building the login script from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Til3oVNlho4

As seen in the comments, I have the same error with the user_exist function. Can anyone help me find out what I did wrong or what I should do to fix the problem?

The problem is: when i execute this code, I am seeing a blank page. I should see the text: exists.

```
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM gebruikers WHERE username = '$username'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please post the relevant code here, you don't expect us to make a video of the answer right?

Comment: Your user_exists() function returns a value to something else, please post that something else.

Comment: Can you post the value of `$username`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the query:

```
function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM gebruikers WHERE username = '$username'");
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

When you need to use a php variable to compose a string, you must "escape" this from the quotation marks.Try this instead:

```
function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM gebruikers WHERE username = '".$username."'");
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```